# Cyclic or multiple cascade paths error with EF CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I develop an asp.net mvc solution with **Entity Framework Code First** and I got the error:

`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Transports_dbo.Shippers_ReceiverId' on table 'Transports' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

This occurred when starting the solution in the process of creation of the database.

Here are my models:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Shipper Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual Shipper Receiver { get; set; }
}

public class Shipper
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

If I comment the `public virtual Shipper Receiver { get; set; }` then it works so this is the cyclic problem.

Does anyone can help me on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complex 'self-bound' or 'multiple to same' relationships, you need to explicitly define the relationships - best using fluent configuration.

e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transport>()
    .HasRequired(at => at.Sender)
    .WithMany(a => a.TransportsAsSender)
    // .HasForeignKey(at => at.SenderId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Transport>()
    .HasRequired(at => at.Receiver)
    .WithMany(a => a.TransportsAsReceiver)
    // .HasForeignKey(at => at.ReceiverId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...that assumes you also add:

```
public ICollection<Transport> TransportsAsSender { get; set; }
public ICollection<Transport> TransportsAsReceiver { get; set; }
```

...to the `Shipper`

Or just use...

```
.WithMany() // and no collection navigation properties
```